# PayPal Sandbox MassPay: You do not have permissions to make this API call

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying send mass payment, for this I have used CURL, but I am getting the error response: `You do not have permissions to make this API call`,

My credentials are correct. Here is my full code:

```
$unsername = '****';
        $password = '****';
        $signature = '****';
        $personal_email = '****@gmail.com';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $unsername
                . "&".$password
                . "&".$signature
                . "&METHOD=MassPay"
                . "&VERSION=90"
                . "&RECEIVERTYPE=EmailAddress"
                . "&CURRENCYCODE=USD"
                . "&L_EMAIL0=".$personal_email
                . "&L_AMT0=35.95");
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        $result = urldecode($result);
        $data = parse_str($result,$responseArray);
        $jsonResponse = $responseArray;


        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($jsonResponse);
        die;
```

Response :

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2020-01-20T14:41:52Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => f1f011edab2bd
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 90
    [BUILD] => 54022052
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Authentication/Authorization Failed
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => You do not have permissions to make this API call
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

Comment: You may need to check your API permissions in the account or contact PayPal about this issue, as it's a permission issue, not a code issue.

Comment: can you help me where we need to add permission

Answer (score 0):

Go to developer.paypal.com .
You should have an application, "Default Application" or some other created name.

Select it and you can change the settings:

[image]

(I'm not 100% sure that the highlighted one is the right permission, I never used that functionality)

If you don't have access to the API settings, you should ask to who provided the API keys to you.

Comment: What you highlighted would be great for Payouts, but he's not using Payouts nor a REST application nor a clientID/secret.  Instead, he's doing an old classic MassPay API  call with classic NVP API credentials, for some reason -- which is very old stuff and not recommended.  Switching all his code over to integrate with the new REST API + Payouts would indeed be much preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using the old MassPay API for anything.

Instead, integrate Payouts: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/

---

For later use in live, there are prerequistics, which are the same for Payouts as for MassPay: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/

(if a live account has been enabled for MassPay it has been enabled for Payouts, and vice-versa, the business toggle is one and the same -- but must be requested and approved)